# Laptop black screen blinking

Tags: 18.04

I made the swap from Win10 to Ubuntu, but I'm having an issue now.

About once every hour or so, my laptop will go black, but with my mouse still visible and movable (I think it first goes full black, and then after ~1 sec my mouse pops up). It'll stay black for about ~3-5 sec before the screen comes back. Now, a couple years ago, I experienced the same exact thing on my Win7 desktop, and every time it was because the nvidia driver crashed. In my laptop though, it has integrated graphics, so I'm not sure what the issue is or why it's so identical to my previous problem. What should I do to troubleshoot this?

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64. Dell Inspiron 13-5378

Answer (score 2):

I discovered there was an issue with the gyroscope, causing it to for just a millisecond think that it was sideways. This initiated the "Let me turn into tablet mode" before instantly initiating the "Let me go into desktop mode" operation - only showing me the intermediate black screen stage. This was discovered by randomly deciding to go into tablet mode one day, and noticing that the black screen thing happened during the transition, leading me to hypothesize that the gyroscope was the issue. Turning off auto-rotation indeed fixed the issue.